# Custom control content being used twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have a custom control in which I extended `ToggleButton` to support changing colors when the user clicks on it. It utilizes setting the `ControlTemplate` for the `Border` as follows:

```
<ToggleButton
    x:Class="KwTools.Wpf.Controls.ToggleButtonControls.ColorChangingToggleButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Focusable="False">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="toggleButtonContentPresenter" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="toggleButtonContentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

The problem is if I want to use this control and modify the `Border`, say as follows:

```
<cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton x:Name="foo" cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton.ToggledBackground="Orange" 
                                cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton.ToggledForeground="Yellow"
                                Content="Test it"
                                Background="Yellow" Foreground="Red"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
   <Border CornerRadius="3"/>
</cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton>
```

Then I get this error:

> The property 'content' is set more than once.

How do I get this so that I can edit the custom control's border here?

Answer (score 0):

> Then I get the error "The property 'content' is set more than once.

You do exactly what the error states, you set the content twice.

1. You set the content via the `Content` attribute here: `Content="Test it"`
2. You set the content directly within the tags: `<Border CornerRadius="3"/>`

Remove one of these two so the content is only set once.

> How do I get this so that I can edit the custom control's border here?

When you add a border as content it does not modify or replace the border from the control template, it adds it as child, but that is not what you want.

If you want to customize the border of your control, add a `TemplatedBinding` to the `CornerRadius` property of `Border`, since `ToggleButton` does not have this property.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" Focusable="False">
       <ContentPresenter x:Name="toggleButtonContentPresenter" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
    </Border>
    <!-- ...other code. -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then create a style based on your default style and customize the `CornerRadius`.

```
<Style x:Key="MyColorChangingToggleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}}">
   <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
</Style>
```

Finally, apply it to your toggle button using `StaticResource`.

```
<cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton x:Name="foo"
                                Style="{StaticResource MyColorChangingToggleButtonStyle}"
                                Content="Test it"
                                ...>
```

---

Update for your comments. You get the resource not found error, because the style of your control is defined inside your control's XAML, so you cannot reference it this way.

To solve this, you have to extract the style and define it in a resource dictionary that can be accessed from where you define the derived style, e.g. the application resources in `App.xaml`. Then you can also remove your `ToggleButton` XAML, it is not needed anymore.

```
<!-- Explicit style for referencing via static/dynamic resource -->
<Style x:Key="ColorChangingToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Focusable="False">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="toggleButtonContentPresenter" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="toggleButtonContentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{Binding CheckedForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Implicit style, automatically applied to all of your custom controls in scope -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColorChangingToggleButtonStyle}"/>
```

Usually (but not mandantory), you would create a separate custom control project and where you define the class and then you would create a style like above, explicit for referencing by name and implicit so that it is applied to all control instances of this type. You would put this style in one of the theme resource dictionaries, e.g. `Generic.xaml`, see these references for further information.

- [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [Define and Use Shared Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#define-and-use-shared-resources)

Comment: Tried to incorporate this but getting error on the BasedOn saying " The resource "{x:Type cctb:ColorChangingToggleButton}" could not be resolved."

Comment: @kw1jybo Updated. The style cannot be referenced this way if it is embedded in the control.

Comment: @kw1jybo Does this answer your question?